# Setting an Enum value based on incoming String

Tags: java, string, attributes, enums

I have a number of setter methods which take an enum. These are based on incoming objects attribute. Rather than write a bunch of these is there a way around having to hard code say 10 different case statements. Would there be a way to create a reusable method?

```
//Side class declared as
public final enum Side

//How I initialise side
static Side side = Side.SELL;//default

//method to set object
Obj.setSide(sideEnum(zasAlloc.getM_buySellCode()));

//How I am implementing it
    public static Side sideEnum(String buysell)
    {

        if(buysell.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            side = Side.SELL; //default 
        }
        else if(buysell.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            side = Side.BUY; 
        }

        return side;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a simple object map:

```
private static HashMap<String, Side> sideMap = new HashMap<String, Side>(7);
static{
    sideMap.put("B", Side.BUY);
    sideMap.put("S", Side.SELL);
}
```

and simply using

```
Obj.setSide(sideMap.get(zasAlloc.getM_buySellCode()));
```

Answer (score 26):

You can implement that functionality in your `Enum`.

```
public enum Side {

    BUY("B"), SELL("S"), ...

    private String letter;
    private Side(String letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public static Side fromLetter(String letter) {
        for (side s : values() ){
            if (s.letter.equals(letter)) return s;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

You could also do this as a helper static method if you can't edit `Side`.

```
public static Side fromString(String from) {
    for (Side s: Side.values()) {
        if (s.toString().startsWith(from)) {
            return s;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException( from );
}
```

The above method assumes your strings correspond to the names of you enums.

Comment: Minor comment, if you have a lot of enums and the `fromLetter()` method is called often, it may make sense to create a static `HashMap` to make lookup/retrieval faster. But your solution makes perfect sense!

Comment: @Peter, correct.  This is just the quick and dirty way.  But the hashmap is definitely worth noting.

Answer (score 6):

Enums have valueOf() method that can be used to convert from String. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: ENUM1("one","1","I")

Create your own method similar to value of such as getEnum(String s).  This would allow you to return ENUM1 for any of the attribute values.  valueOf works fine for many cases though.

Comment: Comment it's more the kind that if the string that comes in is "d" it maps to static enum side.DOG

Comment: @Will, this is why you need to provide some code, otherwise we're all left shooting in the dark.

Comment: I realise this but Unfortunately. I working with two Objects I do not have access to the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need smth like:

```
Obj.setSide(Side.valueOf(zasAlloc.getM_buySellCode()));
```